# num_rows issue with returning rows from SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have an issue. I am trying to find out if a user's email already exists in the database here is my query:

```
$stmt1 = "select EmailAddress from customers where EmailAddress = ' .$emailaddress. '";
 $result = $db->query($stmt1);
 if($result->num_rows === 0){

     $Err = "";

 } else {

     $Err = 'This user is already registered login instead.';

 }
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't seem to get num_rows to return something I can work with. Shouldn't this query return 0 if no records are found or number of rows if there is a record?

Comment: You do not need concatenation in your query. Remove the `.` before and after `$emailaddress`.

Comment: `where EmailAddress = ' .$emailaddress. '";` --- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Try using a `==` check, not a `===`.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
$stmt1 = "SELECT EmailAddress FROM customers WHERE EmailAddress = '".$emailaddress."'";
```

Comment: why *use:*?.................

Comment: Whats the difference between == and === ?

Comment: If the `$result->num_rows` returns you string (which is not the case) : The  `'0' == 0` check would be false, whereas `0 == 0` is true. It's not very important, but according to me it looks cleaner.

Comment: Shouldn't i be able to use 'if($result->num_rows > 0)  as well...?

Comment: Indeed ! It **MUST** !

Comment: I want to do a select before an insert. The insert statement is a prepared statement and works flawlessly. The script gives no errors but jumps right to the insert statement as if the select statement didn't exist. Is there an order for prepared statements when doing a select (check if user exists before insert)? I want this handled by php not mysql.